# Server (inframe) integration - hide fields and external fonts

Tags: opayo

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a real GOOD LOOKING server integration experience without any personal input fields showing up when user is forwarded to SagePay to capture card details.

In our application we have a smooth wizard-like process where we capture personal information such as name/delivery address and reviewing the order before paying. When the user is forwarded to SagePay all the information is repeated once again (editable) which just looks awful! :(

According to your docs all fields must be included in the forms.

Question1: Is it OK to render hidden fields such as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cardfirstnames">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:if test="$transactiontypeid != 15">
            <xsl:value-of select="payment-model/transaction/billingfirstnames"/>
        </xsl:if>   
    </xsl:attribute>
</input>
```

Question2: According to docs it's not allowed to load external images. We are using external fonts from Google Fonts. Is there any possibility to load them?

BR

Niclas

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use one of the other template types that are already available - using the Responsive or DefaultNoAddr templates would solve this issue. Alternatively, you can just remove them from the xslt
2. Fonts need to be hosted by Sage Pay. Nothing external is permitted on the payment pages.